# Error with React.Lazy(), "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, create-react-app

I'm fairly new to React so I started my app with create-react-app.

I keep getting the following error when trying to import react components with `React.Lazy()`:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:45)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Import code:

```js
const AssetDetailsContent = React.lazy(() => import('./AssetDetailsContent'));
```

Export code:

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AssetDetailsContent);
```

Most other answers mention webpack configs but as I don't have one and already tried a few that supposedly fixed other's issues, I was thinking it may be an issue with React-Redux.

Comment: Definitely seems like it must be a weird config issue. I just ran create-react-app with (version 3.0.1) of react-scripts, check your package.json, and this worked fine out of the box with react-redux

Comment: @zackkrida I'm also using version 3.0.1 of react-scripts, react-redux 7.1.0, and have not modified my package.json aside from adding modules.